# Scriptural source for saying animal sacrifice and non vegetarian food for Brahmins are not for Kali Yuga

Tags: vedas, manu-smriti, kali-yuga, smriti, sacrifice

One can see ample amount of evidences for animal sacrifice and Brahmins eating meat in Vedic and Smriti literature.

When I pointed out this to a learned Pandit, he just said it has been forbidden in Kali Yuga. I didn't get the opportunity to ask him for the source of this claim.

Is this true? What's the scriptural basis for it?

Comment: Related answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excerpt from the book Hindu Dharma The Universal Way of Life,( Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan publication) contain speeches of Sri Sri Sri Chandrasekharendra Saraswathi MahaSwamiji (at various times during the years 1907 to 1994).   available, in this link gives clarification on this.

https://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part5/chap24.htm

> **Asvalambham gavalambham sanyasam palapatrikam
> Devarena sutotpattim kalau panca vivarjayet**
> Asvamedha sacrifice, gomedha sacrifice, sannyasa,etc. these things are forbidden in this age"
> Brahma Vaivarta Purana
> (Kṛṣṇa-janma-khaṇḍa 185.180
> Ref.courtesy
> vanisource.org/wiki/CC_Adi_17.164 –

> The following are to be eschewed in the Kali age: horse and cow sacrifices, meat in the sraddha ceremony, sannyasa. 
> **Hindu Dharma The Universal Way of Life**

Comment: Can you quote the exact verse from Brahma Vaivarvata Purana?? Where there? Like Chater and verse??

Comment: Krishna Janma khanda

Comment: Sure. Will update after some time

Comment: Update Brahma-vaivarta Purāṇa (Kṛṣṇa-janma-khaṇḍa 185.180 https://vanisource.org/wiki/CC_Adi_17.164

Comment: But  it also says Sannyasa is not for Kali Yuga???

Comment: But the OP is asking for Brahmins eating meat and not about offering in Shraddha..

Comment: @HariKumar maybe its after marraige sanyas

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow it simply says Sannyasam. And nothing else is said.

Comment: Puri shankaracharya comments on this by saying till there are agnihotri brahmins one can take sanyas

Comment: @HariKumar
If your q. asks reg.. consumption of non veg. food , independent of the context of shraddha and sacrifices,a part of this ans, may ans. your question. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30431/does-parashara-smriti-allow-eating-non-vegetarian-food
 .If you / moderators opine that this ans is a duplicate of the one mentioned in prev comment , please mark so .

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow yes thank you

Comment: @Athrey thank you Athrey, I have accepted the answer.